# Dask Gateway Setup on Azure

Tags: dask, dask-gateway

I am trying to setup dask gateway in AKS. Following the documentation I was able to start the dask gateway server in AKS. We have also hosted a separate jupyternotebook instace within the same cluster. When I try to access the gateway server from this jupyternotebook instance its failing with the below error :

[image]

In the dask gateway documentation it shows accessing the gateway server using an ip address. But in actual setup we would be using a url, right? How can I configure dask gateway helm chart for this